# Style from resource dictionary

Tags: dictionary, combobox, resources, styles, staticresource

I have created a resource dictionary that contains a control template for comboboxes. I have extracted the default combobox control template using XamlWriter and pasted that code to this resource dictionary that I'm working on. Just studying how my modifications to the control template reflect to the control itself. File name is Dictionary1.xaml.

Is it possible to use that control template in every combobox in my test application without typing it to every combobox in Xaml? I would normally set combobox's Style="{StaticResource ComboboxTesting}" but it would be nice if my changes would reflect to every combox in my test application. "ComboboxTesting" is the key in my resource dictionary.

I have come up with this code but naturally it does not work because I can't figure out what to put between Setter.Value tags.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Style">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- Something here... -->
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Thanks,

J.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Window.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- Something here... -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the setter property to anything else than "style", try changing it to height, width, color, font, or anything else but Style.... May be because of you changing the parent style from children setter...